# Correct usage of "to coin a phrase"

Tags: phrases, british-english

I've always thought "to coin a phrase" means to invent a phrase or be the first person to use it.

Today I came across this usage by a reporter [for the Lancashire Telegraph](http://www.lancashiretelegraph.co.uk/sport/football/9266598.Burnley_FC_blog__It___s_tough_balancing_books_and_expectation/#commentsList)

> The Burnley board are damned if they do and damned if they don’t, to
>   coin a Kilby phrase, ‘bet the ranch’.

In this statement, very clearly the reporter is *using Kilby's common phrase* and not making up her own

Some searching [led me to the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/to-coin-a-phrase)

> to coin a phrase
>
> something you say before using an expression that has been very
>   popular or used too much

In this definition this becomes equivalent to **cliched**

The same sentiment is explained at http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/coin-a-phrase.html

So my question is *whether this is universally the case or is it a British English thing*?

Is it now incorrect to use "coin a phrase" with a meaning of "a new phrase" ?

Comment: Have you read Brendon Flood's autobiography? It's a cracking read.

Comment: @AndyF: Nope, I'm not a Clarets fan or anything really. Just an observer. Are you a supporter?

Comment: I am. I confess I thought you might be because I couldn't imagine anyone else reading Burnley articles in the LT. I recommend Flood's book because it's actually only tangentially related to football - it's more about how he grew his property business, moved to Burnley and had to contend with the zealotry of the fans. It's called "Big Club, Small Town, and Me".

Comment: @AndyF: I.. erm.. clicked on .. erm .. some erm.. Blackburn articles first. Are we still friends? Just kidding, I'm a neutral reader of lots of football stuff.

Comment: Haha! I'm really just an armchair supporter now. I moved to live 300 miles away, so it's not like I have a season ticket anymore (although I did in 2009-10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure the reporter knew perfectly well the implications of using *to coin a phrase*, and it wasn't an "ironic" usage in the sense that people say this when trotting out a cliche. It's a *tichy* (tongue-in-cheek) example of *typical British understatement*.

Barry Kilby (manager of Burnley Football Club) has said more than once that he *wouldn't bet the ranch* on the outcome of an upcoming game. The reporter is slightly niggled by this, since the standard (particularly in the UK) expression is *bet the farm*. She's even more niggled because we don't even *have* "ranches" in the UK - but we *do* have a preponderance of foreign (including American) managers of our football clubs.

Personally I think the reporter is taking two or three good-natured pops at what she sees as legitimate targets, while showing her own skill at writing by doing this in so few words.

Edit: Having not actually followed OP's link to the newspaper report itself until now, I've just somewhat sheepishly changed the gender of my pronoun references to reporter *Suzanne Geldard*.

Comment: +1 Bravo; solid analysis of the subtle British humour. As far as I can tell, anyway.

Comment: Smart - so as per my original question, is this the widely accepted usage of "coin a phrase" in the UK?

Comment: @JoseK: This particular one is unusual. The reporter may never have *heard* "bet the ranch" except from Kilby, because (even in the US) it's very much a secondary form. It's often said after a neologism that you may have heard recently yourself, but *think others may not*. So it can mean *"a new coinage I came across recently"*, or *"a coinage I've just come up with"*. Of course, it can be facetiously used of a well-established idiom/cliche too, especially if that cliche does actually fit the current context.

Comment: ...note that Kilby himself could have said *"I wouldn't bet the stadium on tomorrow's game, to coin a phrase"*. That would be quite normal usage. Semi-facetious, if you like, in that he would be slightly adapting an existing idiom. That usage I think is particularly common.

Answer (score 6):

**To coin a phrase** did originally mean to invent a new phrase, but its use now is almost always ironic.

It often seems to be an author's way of excusing him/herself for using a cliche.

Comment: I don't agree that "its use now is almost always ironic" -- in fact I've seen the non-ironic use rather often (where the author was genuinely coining a new phrase, or at least thought he/she was), and the ironic use very rarely.

Answer (score 4):

In eighteenth century thieves slang, a coiner was a counterfeiter.  Knowing this, I had the vague impression that "coining a phrase" was taking someone else's phrase and using it yourself.  You would mint your own.

Comment: Your theory makes sense and I like your explanation. If you could back up your answer with a reference or two others will find your answer to be useful too. (Putting the word, coiner, in italics or bold, would make it stand out more IMHO.)

Answer (score 3):

The OED confirms the current meaning, but with no suggestion that it once meant anything else:

> an expression commonly used ironically to introduce a cliché or a
>   banal sentiment.

The earliest supporting citation is dated 1940. The entry for ‘coinage’, however, includes its figurative use to mean

> The (deliberate) formation of a new word, etc.

Comment: So it **is incorrect** to use it to refer to inventing one's own phrase ? What I mean is any listener *would* understand the speaker is using a cliché?

Comment: I try to avoid the word ‘incorrect’ when discussing language. I suppose a native speaker could precede a genuine quotation with the phrase without being misunderstood, as in, ‘To coin a phrase, “Nothing venture, nothing gain.”’ But I think it would be more usual to hear: ‘As the saying goes, “Nothing venture, nothing gain.”’

Comment: The OED does give that meaning, but it immediately follows this: " c. _spec_. To frame or invent (a new word or phrase); usually implying deliberate purpose; and occasionally used depreciatively, as if the process were analogous to that of the counterfeiter."

Answer (score 1):

As other respondents have said, it's nearly always used jokingly to pretend that the speaker has invented the phrase. However, I've never seen this usage - where the speaker gives credit to someone else (in this case Kilby) but also claims that she's coined the phrase. Seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have always understood coining a phrase to mean inventing a new usage, with "coining" being a synonym for "minting," or newly creating. The other usage makes no sense. Why would anyone, when using a common phrase, add a wordy pretense that they were inventing what everyone knows they did not invent? Isn't that compounding the banality? Why would anyone point out the fact that they are using a commonplace? It is a blatant absurdity, the opposite of British subtlety. That this bizarre meaning even exists is very surprising.