# Etymology of "to coin a phrase"

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

Quite simply — who coined the phrase "to coin a phrase"?

I'm sure it wasn't one person, but it's the origin that is of interest.

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/coin-a-phrase.html

Comment: @mgb That doesn't say who.

Comment: @Kris - I think the closest we're going to get to an answer is in the link provided, i.e. minters.

Comment: @kris it has an author reference for a 1940s use of the exact phrase, and "to coin" in general going back to the C15 - so we are unlikely to get a single name

Comment: etymonline.com shows "to coin a phrase" as late 16th Cent. Whether it's C15 or C16, it's undoubtedly old and the exact originator is unlikely to be found.

Comment: Related: _[Correct usage of “to coin a phrase”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42988/5822)_

Comment: @LewisCarroll: _[What is the General Reference qualification for questions on word or phrase origin?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1128/5822)_

Comment: The close reason given is not correct. Etymonline and OED give 1940 (1898 for 'coin phrases'), but they are inccurate.